# ls to show dates and times in UTC

Tags: time, ls

How do I get the `ls` command to show its dates and times in UTC, instead of localtime?

I don't want to permanently change the local time for my system to do this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One can set the time zone environment variable for each invocation of ls like so:

```
TZ=utc ls -l
```

or set it once with:

```
export TZ=utc
```

in a shell to have it always on, for the remaining duration of the shell session.

Comment: Worth noting that `ls -l --full-time` will display the full time in ISO format with the offset from UTC.

Answer (score 2):

To force UTC, set `$TZ` to UTC:

```
TZ="UTC" ls <options>
```

This will set `$TZ` to UTC just for the duration of this command.